# How can I convert string name date to DateTimeFormat Mysql c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

My string format is Wednesday, June 8, 2016 7:10:29 PM.

```
dateLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();  
timeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
```

I want to change it to datetimeformat including also the daysoftheweek everytime I'm going to save this data to mysql database.

Comment: Question: What is your datatype for this case? If it is datetime, I think you just convert string to datetime and when you want to load it, you can formatting that datetime to string with format you needed.

Comment: my datatype is datetime. you think the field will accept the data with daysoftheweek on it or string months? I didn't try it yet. because the datetime format provided by mysql is MM-DD-YYYY, 00:00:00. it won't accept "Wednesday, June 8, 2016 7:10:29 PM".

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string dateStr = "Wednesday, June 8, 2016 7:10:29 PM";
DateTime  date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
```

**EDIT :** 
To convert date to dd-mm-yyyy
Use tostring with format

```
string newDate = date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

And in your sql pass this string directly parse it in sql side

Comment: It reads as dd/MM/yyyy. Mysql will only accept format of dd-MM-yyyy. how would I do it to change the format but still in a datetime datatype? thanks!

Comment: thanks... I just didn't know that mysql will automatically convert the string datatype to datedatatype. Well, as long as you have the right format. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In `C#` you could supply format when calling `ToString` on `DateTime`.

Since you want Full DateTime format, you could pass `"f"` to `ToString()`

```
dateLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("f");

//output - Thursday, June 9, 2016 4:19 AM
```

Check for more [`standard formats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)